# Two different schema in app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I use two different schema in my web - application. My application works , but I have some error during the compile. How I can configure my application for use multiple schemas ?

My beans:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory
        (DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("base");
    return entityManagerFactory;
}


@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setShowSql(false);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sc1?characterEncoding=UTF-8"); //?characterEncoding=UTF-8
    ds.setUsername("*****");
    ds.setPassword("******");
    return ds;
}
```

My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agents",schema="sc1")
public class Agent {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "agents",schema="sc2")
public class Agent2 {}
```

Error msg:

```
     ERROR SchemaUpdate:261 - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table sc2.agents constraint FK_dhh7a26whpx1a7cqnh646turg foreign key (doc_id) references sc2.Docs (id)
 ERROR SchemaUpdate:261 - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table sc2.agents  (id bigint not null auto_increment)
2016-06-07 14:38:33 ERROR SchemaUpdate:262 - Table 'sc2.agents' already exists
```

etc.

Comment: `My application works, but I have some error during the compile` cannot be true. If you have an `error during compile`, the application will not compile and uncompiled application cannot work. The error messages shown are not compilation errors but runtime errors thrown when you start the application. They indicate that Hibernate cannot make certain changes to schema because those changes already exist in the database. Hibernate is trying to make those changes because of `setGenerateDdl(true);`. You can ignore the messages because the changes already exist or use `setGenerateDdl(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your sc2.Docs (id) the id column is not either primary key or unique key.